# How to make UITextField uneditable during changing the view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a custom cell and declare text field and make it non-editable

```
class SuppliersCutomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    /*Input*/

    @IBOutlet weak var compNameField:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var companyTypeField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        compNameField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        compNameField.enabled = false

         func edit() {
        compNameField.userInteractionEnabled = true
        compNameField.enabled=true
        print("edit")

    }
}
```

When I come to the another class, I am trying to make it editable here.

```
class SuppliersViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
    {
let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Edit"){(UITableViewRowAction,NSIndexPath) -> Void in

            if indexPath.row == 0{

                SuppliersCutomTableViewCell().edit()
            }       
     }    
}
```

When I am calling my method `SuppliersCutomTableViewCell().edit()` it's showing the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can anyone show some sample code for this?

Comment: hi guys i did't get any explanation till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have **not initialised** some of your optionals.So while unwrapping , you are getting `nil`. Try to check if you have initialised your optionals or not before using them.

Comment: how to use uitableviewcell textfield inside viewcontoller.

Comment: Please post new question with more details and code which you tried so far.

Comment: actually i am not able to post new question